# Remove backups older than 7 days except first of every month

Tags: linux, backup, centos, rm

I want to delete backups older than 7 days but keep the first of every month.

The name of the files is: `name_$(date +\%d\%m\%Y).tar.gz`

I want to keep: `name_$(date +\01\%m\%Y).tar.gz`

I want something like this:

```
find /path -mtime +8 -exec rm {} \;
```

Where can I fit in `name_$(date +\01\%m\%Y).tar.gz`?

Maybe using `--exclude name_$(date +\01\%m\%Y).tar.gz`

I'm looking for a one line command.

Don't want subdirectories.

Tried it with echo it doesn't work fine but it shows somw of the 01.

the `--exclude` just doesn't work: `command not found`

Comment: How about scripting out a  move of the "keeper files" that have the "01" characters in the file name to a sub-folder first just beneath where all the other that are to be non-recursively purged after a certain age like `/01Monthly`, `/BackupsRetained`, etc. and then have your other logic do the rest without the exclusion or `--exclude` switch? This way your `01` files are always moving first per the same script that purges and those are always in this other "standard" sub-folder within that same root folder than you purge the 7 day old files from within only that folder and not recursively.

Comment: It doesn't work `--exclude name_01*.tar.gz`? Try with `echo` instead of `rm` before... :)

Comment: I think what you want is something like -prune -o -name 'name_01*.tar.gz' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5659516/using-find-deleting-all-files-directories-in-linux-except-any-one

Answer (score 5):

This works for me under Debian/Ubuntu (and should work under most) :

For example if you have file(s) dated in the following format:

*mybackup_**12-01-2015**.tar.gz*

```
 $ find ./* -name 'mybackup_??-01-*' -prune -o -mtime +7 -exec ls {} \;
```

Command:

- Find all files starting from current folder
- Prune (disregarding/excluding) files with a '01' date match
- and only including files of ≥7 days (mtime)
- Execute `ls` to show what's left.

> If you want to delete them after testing command, just replace `ls` with `rm`.

When you are happy with the command, it also works well as a cron task/job. I have it execute my script once every couple months. (my script uses a mtime of +90 days to cleanup mysql backups)

Answer (score 2):

#### Deleting files older than 7 days except first of month.

```
find . ! -name '*01.tar.gz' -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

This does:

- `find .`: Execute find in the current directory. Replace `.` with any other directory.
- `!` (equivalent to `-not`): Reverse the next operation.
- `-name '*01'`: Finds files that ends with `01.tar.gz`. In my case files ended with date in `YYYYMMDD` format, so this filters out first file of every month. Quotes are required so bash doesn't expand the asterisk. This filter is negated thanks to the previous `!`.
- `-mtime +7`: Filter files that are older than 7 days.
- `-exec rm {} \;`: Executes `rm` on every single selected file. Remove this option when you're testing to get the list of selected files.

---

#### Deleting directories older than 7 days except first of month.

In my case my mongodb backups were stored in separated directories. To purge the old files I executed this:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name 'db_backup_*01' -mtime +7 -exec rm -r {} \;
```

The main changes:

- `-maxdepth 1`: This limits the directory depth search to 1, meaining the search will be limited to the current directory.
- `-exec rm -r {} \;`: To delete directories, `-r` parameter is required to `rm`.